# tensorflow build - CPU / MKL / Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, cpu, intel-mkl

Has anyone succeeded to build tensorflow python wheel with the following configuration:

1. **CPU** (not GPU)
2. OS: **Windows** 7 / server 2012
3. Using Intel **MKL** and/or mkl-dnn
4. **Python 3.6**

I am struggling, for days now, trying to tweak bazel files and cmake files without success.

Would like to know if **someone succeeded and willing to share what he did**.

Thanks, Lior

Answer (score 2):

First off, building tensorflow from source has always been a challenging feat since the early v1.x versions, up to now with v2.x versions. However, as a part of my job, I had to struggle building it first with cmake and later with bazel. I recommend highly against building with cmake. Since it is not officially supported, it does not generate the same binary as bazel version due to different versions of dependencies, and it requires many modifications to cmake files/scripts and even source codes to make it work.

As a great source of info for building tensorflow, I suggest two links:

[1]: [official build docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

[2]: [.bazelrc file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/.bazelrc)

The first link is the official build docs from google, second link is often ignored and it contains various useful tips to your building process. One of those tips is that since version 2.0 up to current (2.9, at the time of writing this), MKL is not supported on Windows/Mac. However, MKL is needed for running many operators on CPU/GPU as correctly pointed out in comments by @Lior-Cohen.

So you need to build tensorflow using bazel with MKL support. So open the official build docs link and follow with the instructions to prepare your environment (Visual Studio, CUDA/CUDNN if desired, msys, python, ...). Download a compatible bazel from its [github repo](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tags). To check bazel compatibility, see [the table](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations). Before running the *bazel build* command, you may set the *BAZEL_VC* environment variable, since bazel may have difficulty finding your build tools. So, change the following command according to the version of your build tools installed at command prompt beforehand:

```
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC
```

Be forewarned that you may encounter many errors during the build. You must read them one by one and solve them. Your mileage may vary, as many errors may be due to failed download attempts, slow internet connection, downtime with online sources, changed file hashes due to changed files in online sources, etc. So be patient and solve them one at a time, reading the error and following the error stack to check the source links or scripts.
One major problem with building TF with MKL is the following error:

```
MASM : warning A4018:invalid command-line option : -B
 Assembling: external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/windows/msvc_wrapper_for_nvcc.py
external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/windows/msvc_wrapper_for_nvcc.py(1) : error A2044:invalid character in file
external/local_config_cuda/crosstool/windows/msvc_wrapper_for_nvcc.py(2) : error A2044:invalid character in file
...
```

Two ways to solve it are proposed, one is suggested on github [issue 25213](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25213) and the other is to create a fake ML64.exe that can process the intended assembly file. Here's the source to a C# snippet that if compiled (as exe with *ML64.exe.config* file) and replaced as original *ML64.exe* on your system can proceed the build process smoothly. Rename the original *ML64.exe* as *ML64-org.exe*. Create a simple C# console project in VS:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ML64
{
    static internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var apr = new AppSettingsReader();
            var dir = apr.GetValue("dir", typeof(string)) as string;
            var ml = apr.GetValue("ml", typeof(string)) as string;

            var importantArgs = args.Skip(2).Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a} {b}");
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ml, importantArgs) { RedirectStandardOutput = true, UseShellExecute = false, WorkingDirectory = dir };
            using (var proc = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                proc.WaitForExit();
                Console.Write(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and change app.config to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <!--Path to your TF source where configure.py resides.-->
        <add key="dir" value="G:\2.9.0"/>
        <!--Path to your ML64 that TF build complains with errors.-->
        <add key="ml" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX64\x64\ml64-org.exe"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The *bazel build* I used for my C++ projects is: `bazel --output_base=g:/base build --config=cuda --config=mkl --config=numa --config=monolithic tensorflow:tensorflow.dll`

For your python projects, you may run the following command: `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --config=mkl --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: 1**

Installing TensorFlow from Source on windows is not generally supported. But you can try building this using bazel or tensorflow cmake build.
Refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

**Solution: 2**

Create Intel optimized conda environment as below:

**conda create -n tf -c intel python=3.6**

To install tensorflow:

**conda install -c intel tensorflow**

This will install tensorflow version 1.2.1 with mkl.
This might help.

Prerequisites: Install Anaconda on your windows machine.

Comment: The intel instruction says `conda install tensorflow-mkl`  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this distribution and it worked fine for me (Windows 7 and 10 64bit, 2x Intel Xeon E5-2637 v3)

https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

Comment: Tx. Do you know if it is using mkl?

Comment: By default yeah, to take advantage of the AMX2 architecture you have to use MKL.

https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#optimizing_for_cpu

Comment: The problem with the Github codes is that their update frequency is not always in-line with how tensorflow updates. Therefore, if the user is not active you might have to wait for quite a while until the next version of TF - MKL. 
Unless of course, you get your hands dirty and make adjustments on his code.

Comment: Tx for your help.
I checked this wheel and unfortunately it does **not have MKL**.

Comment: It is optimized for MKL use, because of the AMX2. What do you mean 'it doesn't have MKL'? 

To run it, install Python MKL from Intel and then pip install the wheel.

Comment: Did a test to run "nn_ops.conv2d" with data_format='NCHW' (which is supported only by tensorflow that was compiled with MKL) on this wheel.
Got "data_format == FORMAT_NHWC Generic conv implementation only supports NHWC tensor format for now."
Test example was taken from: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8151

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the info though!